# Meteor remove published packages

Tags: meteor

I try to port some of my packages to the new meteor 0.9 rc.
2 of 3 did work, the 3rd has a hack in it which does work when installed via `meteor add`.

Is there a way to remove a published package from the meteor package server? I don't want a broken package in the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's currently impossible to remove published packages on meteor's packaging server and on atmosphere.

What you could do however is create a new version that has a empty `Package.onUse`. And a comment why it's empty. This makes your package inert and ensures you that you won't break anyones project.

**Late edit:**

You can now hide it from the search results with set-unmigrated

```
 meteor admin set-unmigrated YOURPACKAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove the package from atmosphere.js but it is possible to hide using .
`meteor admin set-unmigrated PACKAGE-NAME` .  but this will not prevent users from adding the package in their project using .  `meteor add PACKAGE-NAME` .

In this case it makes sense to put empty Package.onUse and update the package as highlighted by Marco in his answer.